# How to find file inside subfolder using regex

Tags: java, regex, file, jenkins

Assuming I have a folder named `xpto` which in turn has multiple subfolders inside, how can I find a file named `example.xyz` inside only the subfolders? (`xpto` folder and the file name are always static. The only thing that is different are the subfolders of xpto)

Note: example.xyz may exist on `/` aswell on `/xpto` and **SHOULD NOT** be returned as a result.

Folder tree (may provide a clearer view):

```
/
|--- xpto
   |--- subfolder1
      |--- example.xyz
   |--- othername
      |--- example.xyz
   |--- yetanotherrandomname
      |--- example.xyz
   |--- example.xyz
|--- example.xyz
```

I'm using java to achieve this.

So far I wasn't able to achieve much, but using something like

`^xpto|example.xyz$` got me the `example.xyz` that exist on `/` and on `/xpto` (which are the files that I don't want)

Also using something like `^xpto\\\\.*\\\\example.xyz$` returns 0 results.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

**EDIT** 
Since there are a lot of questions in the air this is the code I'm using to get the file I need (This code can't be changed, because this code belongs to a plugin of Jenkins (thinBackup) and I'm trying to add additional files to the backup. That is the code used by that plugin to do that)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("missing regex"); //the missing regex
final IOFileFilter addFilesFilter = new RegexFileFilter(pattern);

final IOFileFilter filter = FileFilterUtils.and(addFilesFilter);

try {
//origin and destination being both File's. Not very important.
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(originPath, destinationPath, filter);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: From where are you obtaining the string you are attempting to match with your regex?

Comment: So `.../xpto/subfolder/example.xyz` is valid, but `.../example.xyz` and `.../xpto/example.xyz` is invalid?

Comment: This should handle *most* cases `^.*xpto\/+.*\/+example.xyz$`, watch out for situations where you have a directory similar to `blaxpto/subfolder/example.xyz`.

Comment: Can you show your java code where you are picking the file paths and applying regex on it to filter?

Comment: @JonnyHenly your regex did not work, using the code I just added.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi look at the edit plz :) thx btw

Comment: @VGR I think you didnt understand the problem :p

Comment: @notihs sorry, forgot about Java regex syntax. Try using `(?m)^/?xpto/+.+/+example.xyz$`, the `(?m)`, multiline modifier tells Java to match `^` and `$` with new line characters rather than the start and end of the entire string. This will match `/xpto/.../example.xyz` and `xpto/.../example.xyz`, note that `...` could contain other directories, for instance `/xpto/xpto/xpto/example.xyz` will be matched as well.

Comment: @JonnyHenly sry but it didn't work out :/ I think that what I'm trying to do is impossible with a regex. It seems that the regex needs to find my folder, then the subfolder, and then the file i want. Something like this ^xpto|subfolder|example.xyz$. However, this will get all the examples.xyz on / and /xpto. Worse than that, I need to specify, in some way the subfolder name. It can't just be something like (.*) because that would catch all.
The solution that i found was simply changing the file location to a easier location to catch with a simpler regex aswell. Thanks anyway!